# How to check if a specific executable has a live process

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I want to write a script that checks periodically if a specific executable has a live process, something like this:

```
psping [-c ###] [-t ###] [-u user-name] exe-name
-c - limit amount of pings, Default is infinite
-t - define alternative timeout in seconds, Default is 1 sec
-u - define user to check process for. The default is ANY user.
```

For example, `psping java` will list all processes that are currently invoked by the `java` command.

The main goal is to count and echo the number of live processes for a user, whose executable file is `exe-name`, `java` in the above example.

I wrote a function:

```
perform_ping(){

      ps aux | grep "${EXE_NAME}" | awk '{print $2}' | while read PID
         do
           echo $PID # -> This will echo the correct PID

           # How to find if this PID was executed by ${EXE_NAME}
         done
    fi
    sleep 1
}
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to check if a specific executable file has a live process.

Comment: You used `grep $EXE_FILE` so I assume all PID found are what you want. Why would the PID be not executed by `$EXE_FILE`?

Comment: I might suggest using `lsof $EXE_FILE`, which lists processes that uses the executable.

Comment: `EXE_FILE` is not the executable file, it is the name of the executable, for example, java or chrome, I've edited the code hope its clearer now

Comment: Um, I assume the user command is something like `java file.java` and you want to detect how many process are invoked by `/usr/bin/java`?

Comment: that's right, for example, `psping java` will list all processes that are currently running and are executable by `java`, Does every executable can be found under `/usr/bin/exe-name`?

Comment: Not all executable are under `/usr/bin`, but ok it's more clear now. You may add the above comment to problem statement for clarity to future visitors. Answering.

Comment: `psping` is the name I gave the script, eventually, I would like to add it as a command. it has nothing to do with the windows `psping` command, it might be called `process_ping` for example. im running Linux CentOs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To list all processes that opens a file, we can use the `lsof` command. Because an executable must be opened in order to be run, we may just use `lsof` for this purpose.

The next problem is that when we run a java file, we simply type `java some_file`, and if we issue `lsof java` it will coldly says that `lsof: status error on java: No such file or directory` because the `java` is actually `/usr/bin/java`.

To convert from `java` to `/usr/bin/java` we can use `which java`, so the command would be:

```
lsof $(which $EXE_FILE)
```

The output may looks like this:

```
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tracefs file system /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
  Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND PID    USER  FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF  NODE NAME
python3 26969  user txt    REG    8,1  4526456 15409 /usr/bin/python3.6
```

In this case I searched `python3` as `lsof $(which python3)`. It will report the PID in the second field. But when there's another user that invokes `python3` too, `lsof` will issue the warning on stderr like the first two lines because it cannot read other users info. Therefore, we modify the command as:

```
lsof $(which python3) 2> /dev/null
```

to suppress the warning. Then we're almost there:

```
lsof $(which python3) 2> /dev/null | awk 'NR > 1 { print $2 }'
```

Then you can use `read` to catch the PID.

---

**Edit: how to list all processes for all users?**

By default `lsof` doesn't read process for a specific file, but after further reading `man lsof` I found that there are options that meet your needs.

> -a       causes list selection options to be ANDed.
>
> -c c     selects  the  listing of files for processes executing the command that begins with the characters of c.  Multiple commands may be specified, using multiple -c options.
>
> -u s     selects  the listing of files for the user whose login names or user ID numbers are in the comma-separated set s.

Therefore, you can use

```
lsof -c java
```

to list all commands that are run by `java`. And to see a specific user, add `-u` option as

```
lsof -a -c java -u user
```

`-a` is needed for the AND operation. If you run this command you will see multiple entry for a process, to unique them, run

```
lsof -c java 2> /dev/null | sed 1d | sort -uk2,2
```

Also please notice that users may run their own java in their path and therefore you have to decide which one to monitor: `java` or `/usr/bin/java`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer , if I understand you correctly this will list the open process by `exe-name` only for the current user since `lsof` is bounded to the current user, can I modify it to list all running process that got executed by `exx-name` for all users?

Comment: Edited above, see if it meets your needs.